# Why C#8 Default implementations of interface members will report an error

Tags: resharper, .net-core-3.0, c#-8.0, default-interface-member

Why C#8 Default implementations of interface members will report an error?

```
public interface Logger
{
    void Info(string message);
    void Error(string message);
    // C#8 Default implementations of interface
    void Warn(string message)
    {
        // "interface method cannot declare a body" error message
    }
}
```

and

.NET Core 3.0 is configured as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: Its a shame... this is a good question. Can you post your actual code as well thanks

Comment: I have removed the screenshot of the code and added the code sample (because it was short code). Do note that to allow others reproduce your problem it is **very** useful to add the code as text, not screenshots.

Comment: It's resharper. Somebody knows how to fix this? Doesn't work in 2019.2.2.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a Resharper/Rider bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-474628

Answer (score 6):

The feature is sound and your setup is correct. Also the following works for me, i can compile and run the following in *.Net Core 3*

```
class Program
{
   interface IDefaultInterfaceMethod
   {
      void DefaultMethod()
      {
         Console.WriteLine("I am a default method in the interface!");
      }
   }
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
   }
}
```

**Note though**, i get your error in the IDE!! yet there was no error in the *error window*. However, it still compiles and runs so it is not C#8.. Seeing this is a *sure-sign* something else is the issue

[image]

In Short, this is likely a *Resharper* problem, when i suspended *Resharper* the false positive went away

Comment: I would change "_yet_ _it_ _still_ _compiles_ _and_ _runs_" into "yet it still compiles and runs so it is not C#8"